# Order of from and to values in SQL Between

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a simple procedure in SQL Server as below.

```
DECLARE @num int;
SET @num = 5;
SELECT @num WHERE @num BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
SELECT @num WHERE @num BETWEEN 10 AND 1;
```

If you run this, the first select statement gives you 5 and the second one returns nothing.
I am confused as to why this is, as both cases should return true as 5 is between 10 and 1 as well as 1 and 10.

Is there is a reason why the `BETWEEN 10 AND 1` line defies logic?

Thanks

Comment: You should always start with the lower value and as second value a value that is higher then the first one.

Comment: Because that's what the manual says.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the standard (was decided to be) for SQL.

```
x BETWEEN a AND b
```

stands for

```
( a <= x )  AND  ( x <= b )
```

See page 211 of: [**SQL-92 specifications (a copy of a review draft)**](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

> ```
>    8.3  <between predicate>
>
>      Function
>      Specify a range comparison.
>
>      Format
>      <between predicate> ::=
>           <row value constructor> [ NOT ] BETWEEN
>             <row value constructor> AND <row value constructor>
>
>      Syntax Rules
>      1) The three <row value constructor>s shall be of the same degree.
>      2) Let respective values be values with the same ordinal position
>         in the two <row value constructor>s.
>      3) The data types of the respective values of the three <row value
>         constructor>s shall be comparable.
>      4) Let X, Y, and Z be the first, second, and third <row value con-
>         structor>s, respectively.
>      5) "X NOT BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "NOT ( X BETWEEN Y AND
>         Z )".
>      6) "X BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "X>=Y AND X<=Z".
> ```

---

The only RDBMS I know that is away from the standard (and follows your logic) is MS-Access.

Comment: Well, that's close to the truth.  BETWEEN is implemented differently (inclusive/exclusive) on different platforms.

Comment: @Dems: I didn't know that. Can you please provide more info (which dbms, which platforms and what are the differences)?

Answer (score 2):

The `BETWEEN` statement can be translated as

```
WHERE @num >= 1 and @num <= 10.
```

Turning this around makes

```
WHERE @num >= 10 and @num <= 1.
```

Which won't return much.

Comment: In conjunction with the other answers regarding the SQL standard it makes sense, but otherwise it looks like a shortfall on the BETWEEN function.

Comment: Only if you consider it in english language. Its really just a shorthand for a common case.

Answer (score 2):

That's the way it's designed.

```
WHERE 5<test_expression> BETWEEN 10<begin_expression> AND 1<end_expression>;
```

Does not meet the requirement for a BETWEEN match;

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of
>   test_expression is greater than or
>   equal to the value of begin_expression
>   and less than or equal to the value of
>   end_expression.